# Generate multiple unique sets of divs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to generate multiple unique sets of divs within the existing div with an id of row. I would like the output to be this:

```
<div id="row">

 <div>fluffy</div>
 <div>soft</div>
 <div>green</div>

 <div>mittens</div>
 <div>coarse</div>
 <div>fire</div>   

 <div>whiskers</div>
 <div>none</div>
 <div>grey</div>      

</div>
```

However my output is currently this:

```
<div id="row">

<div>fluffy, soft, green</div>
<div>mittens, coarse, fire</div>
<div>whiskers, none, grey</div>

</div>
```

I am using the following jquery:

```
function cats(catName, catFur, catEyes) {
$("#row").html('<div>' + catName + '</div>' + '<div>' + catFur + '</div>' + '<div>' + catEyes + '</div>');
}

$cat1 = ["fluffy", "soft", "green"];
$cat2 = ["mittens", "coarse", "fire"];
$cat3 = ["whiskers", "none", "grey"];

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

function catGenerator() {
    $catVars = [$cat1, $cat2, $cat3];
    cats($catVars[0], $catVars[1], $catVars[2] );
}

catGenerator();
```

});

My overall goal is to be able to automate the number div sets to be generated, for example, there are 3 div sets to be generated here, so instead of listing every cat array under the catGenerator function, it would automatically know how many sets to generate. I believe this would be implemented with a for loop, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I feel overall I am missing a bigger concept here, and I would love to know if anyone has a better way of going about this overall problem, a more best practices approach. Thanks!

codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IfKek

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function catGenerator() {
    $catVars = [$cat1, $cat2, $cat3];
    for (var i = 0; i < $catVars.length; i++) {
        cats($catVars[i][0], $catVars[i][1], $catVars[i][2]);
    }
}
```

Actually "$catVars" is a two dimensional array.

```
$catVars[0][0] =  "fluffy";
$catVars[0][1] =  "soft";
$catVars[0][2] =  "green";
$catVars[1] = ["mittens", "coarse", "fire"]
$catVars[2] = ["whiskers", "none", "grey"];
```